# Routing does not work in my asp.net app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have 4 routes defined 5 different urls. Tested a lot with RouteDebugger but can not solve.

The problem is that Top 2 links always use **{controller}/{action}/{id}** this route which is root1 and can not redirect to proper pages.

**Links**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Go Index by name", "Page", "Home", new { name="contact"}, null)

@Html.ActionLink("Go Index by id", "Index", "Admin", new { id=2}, null)


@Html.ActionLink("Go Index by id and name", "Page", "Home", new { name = "contact", id = 2 }, null)


@Html.ActionLink("Root Admin", "Index", "Admin")


@Html.ActionLink("Root", "Index", "Home")
```

**Here is the Map.Route**

```
    routes.MapRoute("root1",
      "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
       new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index" });

    routes.MapRoute("root2",
        "{controller}/{action}/{name}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Page" });

    routes.MapRoute("root3", 
        "{controller}/{action}/{name}/{id}", 
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Page" });

    routes.MapRoute("root4", 
        "{controller}/{action}/{name}", 
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", name = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the routes I have set up and it seems to hit each one correctly.

Note that `root3` has been moved to the top since `root2` will match that as well. also, the validation for `root1` with `id` as King Julian suggested

The route:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Root Admin", "Index", "Admin")
```

should not match `root1` nor `root2` since there is no default for `id` and `name` respectively in the route definition

```
routes.MapRoute("root3",
     "{controller}/{action}/{name}/{id}",
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Page" });

routes.MapRoute("root1",
      "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index" },
      new { id = @"\d+" });

routes.MapRoute("root2",
      "{controller}/{action}/{name}",
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Page" });

routes.MapRoute("root4",
      "{controller}/{action}/{name}",
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", name = UrlParameter.Optional     
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How to handle @Html.ActionLink("Root Admin", "Index", "Admin") route problem . I don't want to assign id = 0 to make it work. Any solution please?

Comment: @pirzada, I don't understand what the problem is - that link is matched by `root4` and displayed as `http://foo.com/Admin` which I believe is the correct thing to do

Answer (score 1):

Add constraints to your routes. For example:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "root1",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index" },
    new {id = @"\d+" }
 );
```

Will ensure that root1 only matches when id is an integer. Otherwise, root2 would catch it.

Comment: Thanks I did what you said but my @Html.ActionLink("Root Admin", "Index", "Admin") catch root1 . This should hit root4. Please help